# Threads and stringbuilder

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have this code which should output String length = 10000, but i keep getting different outputs, and i am confused on how is it exactly happening? is that because for example thread 1 will append like 95 times and then another thread will interrupt thread 1 eg: thread 2, and then thread 2 will append up to 98 before getting interrupted by t3 etc.. ?

Comment: StringBuilder is not thread-safe. You can't use one from concurrent threads. Replace it with a thread-safe StringBuffer, and you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: read this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860173/what-does-stringbuilders-are-not-thread-safe-mean

Comment: `StringBuilder` makes no guarantees of being thread-safe. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/26860203/2478398.  From the documentation: 'This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread'

Comment: If you have a look at the source code of `StringBuilder` you'll see that there's a good chance for the appended characters to be written into the same location of the target array or that the count won't be correct. That's because the class is not meant to be used concurrently. Hence your 100 threads should append 100 chars each (no interrupts) but some will be overwritten and thus the final string has a length between 100 and 10000.

Comment: Reading the documentation might sometimes be useful. Literally second sentence says "This class provides an API compatible with StringBuffer, but **with no guarantee of synchronization**"

Comment: i know its not thread-safe, but i am more curious on how the threads interact together to produce such an output.

Comment: they race, and the unsynchronized object is trying to be clever about deciding who wins each time they interact with it, and fails at it. and produces that output. because it's not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is not thread-safe. You can't use one from concurrent threads.

Replace it with a thread-safe `StringBuffer`, and you'll get the result you expect.

Since it's not thread-safe, you can't expect a deterministic result when using it from different threads. For example, the code of StringBuilder might contain something like

```
int newIndex = size();
buffer[newIndex] = appendedCharacter;
```

If two threads execute these two lines concurrently, then both might eecute the first instruction and get the same value for `newIndex`, and then both would insert the new character at the same index. That's called a data race. And such data races are the primary reason why non-threadsafe classes shouldn't be used from multiple threads.

Comment: is it because when we use the StringBuilder we can end up with this scenario? "for example thread 1 will append like 95 times and then another thread will interrupt thread 1 eg: thread 2, and then thread 2 will append up to 98 before getting interrupted by t3 etc.. ?"

Comment: No. No thread is being interrupted. I explained the reason (a data race) in the answer.